# Redirecting to previous url while running the selenium scripts in java

Tags: java, selenium

I am running a Selenium script on LIVE website after several runs in QA environment. But, it is redirecting to previous URL. Though I have added a command to delete all the cookies. And the problem,

```
@BeforeClass(alwaysRun = true)
public void setUp() throws Exception 
{
driver = new FirefoxDriver();
baseUrl = "http://LIVE-URL";
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
}
-------
-------
@Test(priority=1)
public void MenuitemsCheckwithUIAdmin() throws Exception 
{
    driver.get(baseUrl + "/FMSNuFarm/");
    int count=0;
    int errorcount=0;
    String FilePath = "D:\\PMC Automation\\Test Data with Queries-
    Admin.xls";
    FileInputStream File=new FileInputStream(FilePath);
    Workbook W1=Workbook.getWorkbook(File);
    Sheet login_sheet=W1.getSheet("Role_Login");

    System.out.println("\nLOGGING INTO PMC APPLICATION ==>>>>>>>> --");
    System.out.println("\nSelecting User Name and Password from excel 
    --");

    String URL= "http://LIVE-URL";
    System.out.println("\n Successfully Logged into " +URL);
    AssertJUnit.assertEquals(driver.getTitle(), "FMS");
```

It is opening with LIVE URL but once the page is getting loaded, it is redirecting to QA environment.

Comment: Seems like issue with `baseUrl`

Comment: Delete your browser history manually and try again. If it happens again,  then it's from your server, I think, which is redirecting to QA environment not your test code.

Comment: Yes, I have done but not working. Any ways I have given like this, its working now.    String liveurl = "url";
    driver.navigate().to(liveurl);
    driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();